# Average of estimators

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, estimation

Given $X_1,...,X_n$ i.i.d. samples from some unknown distribution, assume that we are given a consistent estimator $\phi_n$ for some R.V. $\phi$. As $n$ gets larger, what can we say about the distance of the following quantities

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\phi_n(X_i) $$ and $$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\phi (X_i)$$

Comment: Is it a homework exercise? If so please add `[self-study]` tag and see http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: No it's not, it's something that I found interesting

Comment: @JohnK , yes I edited my question

Comment: What sense of "distance" is intended?

Comment: Any notion of distance that will say something about the relationship between the two